# When 3D printing a hollow box, what is the best course of action?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

If I need to 3D print a hollow box that can not have any light permeating into the box, what would be the best course of action? Should I 3D print the hollow box as a whole or print out the 6 sides individually and put them together at the end? And if I do the second option, what would be the best way to put the pieces together (design/connect grooves or use glue)?

I am very new to 3D printing so any feedback would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If you print it hollow and as a single object, how do you plan to put things inside? which I assume you want to do, since you say no light inside is allowed. Print it as box and lid separately.

Comment: 3D printing relies on printing solids, it is generally a bad idea to hollow objects yourself, slicers have difficulties when a solid contains internal cavities. You should explain why it needs to be hollow and if you need access to the cavity. Pleas update by [edit] and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! :-)

Answer (score 1):

That depends very much on what your goal is with the box. If it needs to be hollow and you don't need any access to the inside (and also prefer it to be printed in one piece) than the answer provided by user77232 would probably be the best.

Alternatively, if you need access to the inside of the box you would probably be best off printing the box in two pieces. A box and a lid. This way you can print the box without support and also save on material that would otherwise be used as infill.

The amount of light coming into your box also depends on the translucency of your material and brightness of the light source. To find the required wall thickness would be a matter of testing with the desired material.

Answer (score 0):

1. Print it as a whole object
2. Use 20% infill.
3. Profit!

Comment: How is a hollow box hollow if you use 20% infill?

Comment: @FarO Indeed, but sometimes people imply "not solid" with hollow, I've left a comment for the OP to explain what is exactly meant. But technically you are right, 20 % infill is not hollow!